# Signing Requests & Timestamps

Tags: amazon-web-services, common-lisp, amazon-product-api, drakma

Amazon has a handy-dandy tool for testing requests and confirming that you are signing requests correctly they call a 'scratchpad'.  You hand it an unsigned request, put in your authentication information, hit submit, and it spits out a signed request.  Either it or my code is broken, and logic suggests that it's my code, but nothing about this makes sense.  Maybe someone here can see something that I'm not.

If I hand the scratchpad an unsigned request like

`http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=ME&AssociateTag=ME&Keywords=bbq&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService`

I get back

`http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=ME&AssociateTag=ME&Keywords=bbq&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=ItemAttributes&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Timestamp=2017-07-16T15%3A14%3A09.000Z&Signature=4oLDpXEdZ%2BEEPBOOPIMAROBOTiALFPPeICbs%3D`

If I make a request to that URL (*that I got from AMZN's tool*), I get

`Value 2017-07-16T15%3A14%3A09.000Z for parameter Timestamp is invalid. Reason: Must be in ISO8601 format.`

If I manually un-url-encode the timestamp to `2017-07-16T15:14:09.000Z` then it seems to get past that, only to fail with the dreaded `SignatureDoesNotMatch`.

*BUT*

If I make my own signed message using that query string from the signed url above, and the *url-encoded timestamp*, the signatures match!  Which means their backend is using the url-encoded timestamp to compute the signature, but any request by me with a timestamp, url-encoded or not, gives me the "that's not iso8601" error.  All the url-encoding is doing is substituting `%3A` for `:` - not a complex process.

I've confirmed that the locale of the server this is running on is utf-8, and that I'm using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8` as the content-type of the requests, as well as confirmed that the system clock is synced with an authoritative ntp server.

Hopefully someone has seen this or something like it before.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but are you sure the parameters aren't url-encoded twice? ie. drakma may automatically encode them. I can't check myself right now.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll mark it as 'the' answer.  You were completely right.  I thought since I was handing drakma the query string in the url that it wouldn't touch it, and would only do that to the alist passed with `:parameters`.  This is not the case.  The real solution is to pass `:preserve-uri t` to `http-request`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Drakma](http://weitz.de/drakma/) client automatically url-encodes parameters, and it turns the time was encoded twice. It also encodes parameters even if you don't pass them as a parameter list, but directly in the uri. In order to keep to URI unmodified, you have to use `:preserve-uri t`, as explained in the documentation:

> If preserve-uri is not NIL, the given uri will not be processed. This means that the uri will be sent as-is to the remote server and it is the responsibility of the client to make sure that all parameters are encoded properly. Note that if this parameter is given, and the request is not a POST with a content-type of `multipart/form-data', parameters will not be used.